# Getting 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error when I call External WebApi

Tags: c#, api, cors

I found a lot of pages regards to this issue, but none of the Solutions worked.

I have a JavaScript Button in the View that is calling a WebApi method(C#)

```
            $('#btn-Sign-in', this).click(function () {

              var apiUrl = 'https://localhost:44391/api/test';
           fetch(apiUrl).then(response => {
           return response.json();
           }).then(data => {
           // Work with JSON data here
          console.log(data);
           }).catch(err => {
          // Do something for an error here
          });
          });
```

This is My Webapi method that is calling external api:

```
 [RoutePrefix("api")]
public class TestController : ApiBaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("redirectforauth")]
    [RequiresPermission("Home:View")]

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("test")]
    [RequiresPermission("Home:View")]

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ConnectExternal()
    {
        var request = new FlurlRequest("URL of an external website")
                     .SetQueryParam(...)
                     .SetQueryParam(...)
                     .SetQueryParam(...)
                     .SetQueryParam(...);

        var redirectUrl = request.Url.ToInvariantString();

        return  Redirect(redirectUrl);
    }
```

when I am running the project, I am getting this error:

```
 CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Comment: It's not the call to the external API that is failing - http requests from C# don't perform CORS checks (unless you explicitly made it do so) - but rather it's the call to `https://localhost:44391/api/test` - The JS/ page with the button on it is presumably not also on the `localhost:44391` domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is due to your web application URL & C# API URL are not having same origins (not running on same port or same hosts). Two URLs have the same origin if they have identical schemes, hosts, and ports.

EX: Your C# URL https://localhost:44391 is different from your web application URL.

First, to make sure that you are getting the error due to your c# api & not due to the external api, comment out your external api request code inside your action, and return something directly from your api to web application. (If the error is from external Api, that external api needs to handle this to allow access to other origins.)

If you are getting the error due to your c# api & not due to the external api, one approach to do this is, by enabling CORS in your C# WebApi application. You can enable CORS per action, per controller, or globally for all Web API controllers in your application.

You can install this nuget package in your C# API application:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

In App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs, add this code to the WebApiConfig.Register method:

```
config.EnableCors();
```

Next, add the [EnableCors] attribute to your TestController class, with your web application URL.

Ex: if your web application URL is localhost:3000, add it in origins as below.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:3000", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class YourController : ApiController {
    // Your methods...
}
```

Now the AJAX request from your Web Client should work. The GET, PUT, and POST methods are all allowed.

For more details on how to enable CORS & how it works:
[Enable cross-origin requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#:%7E:text=You%20can%20enable%20CORS%20per,API%20controllers%20in%20your%20application.&text=To%20enable%20CORS%20for%20a,attribute%20on%20the%20action%20method)